# How to convert cp866 in utf-8 coding in python

Tags: python

I have file in cp866 encoding, i open it:

```
input_file = open(file_name, 'r', encoding = 'cp866')
```

How i can print() lines from this file like utf-8
I need decode this file to utf-8 and print

Answer (score 0):

Well, the characters read from the file will be decoded and stored in memory as Python strings. You can print them on screen and they should be correct. You can then save the data as utf-8.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

1. `result = text.encode('cp866').decode('cp866').encode('utf8')` - simple convert
2. ```
   data = myfile.read()

   b = bytes(data,"KOI8-R")
   data_encoding = str(b,"cp1251")
   ```

   to cp1251, usualy from cp866 you want to decode to cp1251"
3. If you need decode just once - try [this](https://2cyr.com/decode/) web-site